# Spring task:scheduled or @Scheduler to restrict a Job to run in multiple instance

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

I have one `@Scheduler`  job which runs on multiple servers in a clustered environment. However I want to restrict the job to run in only in one server and other servers should not run the same job once any other server has started it .

I have explored Spring Batch has lock mechanism using some Database table , but looking for any a solution only in spring `task:scheduler`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the solution what I implemented was a the Lock mechanism with Hazelcast and to made it easy to use I also added a proper annotation and a bit of spring AOP for that. So with this trick I was able to enforce a single schedule over the cluster done with a single annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Batch has this nice functionality that it would not run the job with same job arguments twice.

You can use this feature so that when a spring batch job kicks start in another server it does not run.

Usually people pass a timestamp as argument so it will by pass this logic, which you can change it.